# How can I map snap SVG circle via angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, snap.svg

I want to set the radius of snap SVG circle through an input box of angularJS, as I want to make it dynamic on run time.
Anybody who knows the correct way to do it?

```
 <div class="app" ng-app ng-style="disableCircle">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlSizing">
        <label id="rad" style="visibility: hidden">Radius: <input ng-model="rad" type="number" placeholder="How about 300?"></label>
        <div id="circle">
            <svg id="SVG" visibility="hidden" onclick="cInput()" style="height: 800; width: 500; position:absolute; left: 100px;top: 100px;"></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var s = Snap("#SVG");
    var circle = s.circle(150,150,100);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create the circle when the controller loads and do something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrlSizing', function($scope) {      
  $scope.$watch('rad', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal) {
      var s = Snap("#SVG");
      $scope.circle = s.circle(150,150,0);
    } else {
      $scope.circle.animate({r: newVal}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller="ctrlSizing">
        <label id="rad">Radius: <input ng-model="rad" type="number" placeholder="How about 100?"></label>
        <div id="circle">
            <svg id="SVG" style="height: 300; width: 300; position:absolute; left: 0px;top: 50px;"></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```